# How to handle multiple images in a row in bootstrap form?

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to handle row in bootstrap. Kindly check what i am doing:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">

   <?php if($saved_image != ''): ?>

          <div style="width:100px; height:100px">
            <img class="img-thumb" src="<?=$saved_image;?>" alt="saved image" />
            <br>
            <a href="products.php?delete_image=1&edit=<?=$edit_id;?>" class="text-danger">Delete Image</a>

            <!-- Start Another image 2 -->
              <img class="img-thumb" src="<?=$saved_image;?>" alt="saved image" />
              <br>
              <a href="products.php?delete_image=1&edit=<?=$edit_id;?>" class="text-danger">Delete Image</a>
            <!-- End Another image 2 -->

        </div>
        <!-- If Edit Happen - End -->
      <?php else:?>
       <!-- If image empty or user first time add product[data is not saved in the database] -->
       <label for="photo">Product Photo:</label>
       <input class="form-control" type="file" name="photo[]" id="photo" multiple>
     <?php endif;?>

   </div>   <!-- close form-group div -->

          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="description">Description:</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" name="description" id="description" rows="6"><?= $description ;?></textarea>
          </div>
```

Kindly check the below image what I am getting the output:
[image]

I want iron images will show next to each other and if more images are there then it will show on the next line but not below the description box. The description box will be there always where it is showing right now.

Kindly suggest what I am doing wrong. Your suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: try <div style="width:100px; height:100px; display:inline-block;">

Comment: na don't use the `width:100px; height:100px;` shenanigins, instead just have another set of row/cols, seems like you forgot you were using bootstrap

Comment: @Dr J Manish Thanks for the help but unfortunately not working!

Answer (score 0):

you can try with more div tags in your existing code..

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">

 <?php if($saved_image != ''): ?>

      <div class="col-md-6"><!-- This is EDITED-->
        <img class="img-thumb" src="<?=$saved_image;?>" alt="saved image" />
        <br>
        <a href="products.php?delete_image=1&edit=<?=$edit_id;?>" class="text-danger">Delete Image</a>
     </div> <!-- This Is ADDED NEWLY-->
      <div class="col-md-6"> <!-- This Is ADDED NEWLY-->
        <!-- Start Another image 2 -->
          <img class="img-thumb" src="<?=$saved_image;?>" alt="saved image" />
          <br>
          <a href="products.php?delete_image=1&edit=<?=$edit_id;?>" class="text-danger">Delete Image</a>
        <!-- End Another image 2 -->
       </div> <!-- This Is ADDED NEWLY-->
    </div>
    <!-- If Edit Happen - End -->
  <?php else:?>
   <!-- If image empty or user first time add product[data is not saved in the database] -->
   <label for="photo">Product Photo:</label>
   <input class="form-control" type="file" name="photo[]" id="photo" multiple>
 <?php endif;?>
```